# How do I add a QuoteDocument as an Email Attachment

Tags: apex, email, email-template, quote, quote-template

Hey team I'm attempting to auto send a Quote via Email out to a client, but having issues attaching the QuoteDocement to an email via Apex. When the code runs I get a blank PDF.

Thoughts on the below Code?

```
public class QuoteEmail {

@InvocableMethod
public static void QuoteCreateAndEmail(List < Id > quoteIds) {

    AutoQuoteEmail__mdt emailInfo = [SELECT Id, Email_Template_ID__c, Quote_Template_ID__c FROM AutoQuoteEmail__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'Master'];

    List < Quote > quoteList = [SELECT ID, Opportunity.Primary_Contacts_Email__c, Opportunity.ContactId  FROM Quote WHERE ID =: quoteIds];

    //If a Quote is found lets generate a new Qutote PDF
    if (!quoteList.isEmpty()) {
        CreateQuotePDF(quoteList[0].id, emailInfo.Quote_Template_ID__c);
        SendEmail(quoteList[0].id, emailInfo.Email_Template_ID__c, quoteList[0].Opportunity.Primary_Contacts_Email__c, quoteList[0].Opportunity.ContactId  );
    }
}

//Generates a Quote PDF and associates it to the Quote
public static void CreateQuotePDF(String quoteID, String templateID) {

    //This Url creates the pdf for quote
    String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';
    quoteUrl += quoteID;
    quoteUrl += '&headerHeight=190&footerHeight=188&summlid=';
    quoteUrl += templateID;
    quoteUrl += '#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';

    //Create pdf content
    PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl);

    //Document object of quote which holds the quote pdf
    QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument();

    //Get the content of Pdf.
    Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();

    //content assign to document
    quotedoc.Document = b;

    //assign quote id where pdf should attach
    quotedoc.QuoteId = QuoteID;

    //insert the quotdoc
    insert quotedoc;
}

public static void SendEmail(String quoteID, String emailTemplateID, String emailAddress, String contactID) {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.setTargetObjectId(contactID);
    message.setSenderDisplayName('Company Support');
    message.setReplyTo('no-reply@company.com');
    message.setUseSignature(false);
    message.setBccSender(false);
    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    message.setTemplateID(emailTemplateID);
    message.setWhatId(quoteID); //This is important for the merge fields in template to work
    message.toAddresses = new String[]{emailAddress};
    
    //Get and attach the Quote Document
    List<QuoteDocument> QDs = [SELECT Name, Document, ContentVersionDocumentId FROM QuoteDocument WHERE QuoteId = :quoteID];   
    List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
    for (QuoteDocument QD: QDs) {
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName(QD.Name);
    efa.setBody(QD.Document);
    attachments.add(efa);}
    message.setFileAttachments(attachments);
        
     
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {
        message
    };
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

    if (results[0].success) {
        System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
    } else {
        System.debug('The email failed to send: '+results[0].errors[0].message);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: this may be a timing issue - see [this q&a](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/generate-quote-pdf-via-apex-returns-blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments I needed to use a future call out.

```
public without sharing class QuoteEmail {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void QuoteCreateAndEmail(List < Id > quoteIds) {

        List < Quote > quoteList = [SELECT ID, Opportunity.Primary_Contacts_Email__c, Opportunity.ContactId  FROM Quote WHERE ID =: quoteIds];

        //If a Quote is found lets generate a new Qutote PDF
        if (!quoteList.isEmpty()) {
            CreateQuotePDF(quoteList[0].id);
        }
    }

    //Generates a Quote PDF and associates it to the Quote
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void CreateQuotePDF(Id quoteID) {

        AutoQuoteEmail__mdt emailInfo = [SELECT Id, Email_Template_ID__c, Quote_Template_ID__c FROM AutoQuoteEmail__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'Master'];
        Quote newQuote = [SELECT ID, Opportunity.Primary_Contacts_Email__c, Opportunity.ContactId  FROM Quote WHERE ID = :quoteID];
        
        //This Url creates the pdf for quote
        String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';
        quoteUrl += quoteID;
        quoteUrl += '&headerHeight=190&footerHeight=188&summlid=';
        quoteUrl += emailInfo.Quote_Template_ID__c;
        quoteUrl += '#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';

        //Create pdf content
        PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl);

        //Document object of quote which holds the quote pdf
        QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument();

        //Get the content of Pdf.
        Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();

        //content assign to document
        quotedoc.Document = b;

        //assign quote id where pdf should attach
        quotedoc.QuoteId = QuoteID;

        //insert the quotdoc
        insert quotedoc;
        
        SendEmail(newQuote.id, emailInfo.Email_Template_ID__c, newQuote.Opportunity.Primary_Contacts_Email__c, newQuote.Opportunity.ContactId, quotedoc.Id);
    }

    public static void SendEmail(Id quoteID, String emailTemplateID, String emailAddress, Id contactID, Id quotedocID) {

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setTargetObjectId(contactID);
        message.setSenderDisplayName('Company Support');
        message.setReplyTo('no-reply@company.com');
        message.setUseSignature(false);
        message.setBccSender(false);
        message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        message.setTemplateID(emailTemplateID);
        message.setWhatId(quoteID); //This is important for the merge fields in template to work
        message.toAddresses = new String[]{emailAddress};
        
        //Get and attach the Quote Document
        List<QuoteDocument> QDs = [SELECT Name, Document, ContentVersionDocumentId FROM QuoteDocument WHERE QuoteId = :quoteID];   
        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
        for (QuoteDocument QD: QDs) {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName(QD.Name);
        efa.setBody(QD.Document);
        attachments.add(efa);}
        message.setFileAttachments(attachments);
            
         
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {
            message
        };
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

        if (results[0].success) {
            System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        } else {
            System.debug('The email failed to send: '+results[0].errors[0].message);
        }

    }
}
```